# Project Lombok - Value annotation: is it possible to suppress @Getter?

Tags: java, lombok

After scouring the [Lombok feature-list](https://projectlombok.org/features/index.html) and in particular the documentation for the [Getter/Setter](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html) and [`@Value`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value.html) annotations I have not been able to find any setting that suppresses the code generated by `@Getter`.

> In practice, @Value is shorthand for: final @ToString @EqualsAndHashCode @AllArgsConstructor @FieldDefaults(makeFinal = true, level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE) @Getter

This is important as I do not want to leak references to objects that are themselves mutable.

Effective Java references this type of issue in "Item 39: Make defensive copies when needed". It seems that [`@Wither`](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Wither.html) could partly solve this issue by making actual defensive copies but I want to avoid leaking attributes what so ever, regardless of them being mutable.

While it is possible to roll one's own [`@Value`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value.html) annotation that omits the [`@Getter`](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html) I would, of course, prefer not to as that would add unwarranted complexity to the codebase if such a setting already exists.

Comment: it seems that if you do not want to use `@Getter`, you also have to omit `@Value`... Did you try to use `@ToString @EqualsAndHashCode @AllArgsConstructor @FieldDefaults(makeFinal = true, level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)` without the `@Getter` instead? (or maybe with `@Setter` or `@Wither` instead)

Comment: Yes, and it works. It's just so... Muddy

Comment: on the other hand, your use case is somehow special and I think it's ok to put those 3-4 annotations there. At least you do not have to write the rest yourself. Why it is special? well... what does a semi-immutable type help, if you cannot really access its fields/values?

Comment: One thing `@Value` does is that I needn't sprinkle `private final` inside the implementation. Not only does this ensure compile-time feedback to other developers but it's also semantically valuable to succinctly annotate that instances aren't perturbed unnecessarily. However, `private final` does not mean "immutable". Hence, I want to default to the least permissive form of expressing a class first and add accessibility only when needed. I see use for this "feature" very often - so I wouldn't consider it as a special use case at all.

Comment: but I don't get it... you want an immutable type with `private final` fields but with no accessor? What do these fields then bring if they can never be accessed? Or am I missing something? (and if reflection is the only way to access the fields, then I would rather go with the `@Value` instead and add only immutable types in the value-type)

Comment: They matter to the internals of the implementation, as in they are used in multiple methods of the class. However, they shouldn't be available to other classes. By not having accessor methods and using Lombok to reduce boilerplate I (we) get code that is easier to reason about and misuse.

Comment: Are you sure, that you want a `@Value` then? If there are methods which deal with the `private final` fields, that class is probably not an immutable value type. At least I can not think of methods, which do something with those values, which should be part of a value type. But maybe an example could help to enlighten me ;-)

Comment: You might be right. I'm not sure I can convince you, in the comment section, that it is the correct approach and I feel as if an example use case does not matter to the question, i. e. "is there such a feature and I've missed it or does no such feature exist?"

Comment: Depends. The sample may show that you are heading in a direction where some other annotation might be more appropriate or that `@Value` is not the best approach to use. I think there does not yet exist such an annotation as `@Value` without `@Getter`. However such combinations as `@NonFinal @Value` or `@PackagePrivate @Value` are also supported, so you may want to contribute a `@NoGetter` annotation there, even though I cannot yet think of a use case :-)

Comment: @FilipAllberg It sounds like you're making an actual `Class` (as in, a structure with _both_ behavior and data). Immutable data structures (like `@Value` is intended to create) work best when you split your structures into `Value Objects` (classes with no behavior, just data) and `Functions` (classes with just behavior but no data). This also has lots of other benefits too, like ease of testing and reduced (or eliminated) locking in concurrent environments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use:

`@Value
@Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)`

`AccessLevel.NONE` instructs Lombok to not generate the getters. That's the best you can do right now.